# Targeted group game for 8 or 9 players

Tags: playing-cards, board-game-geek

I am a graduate math student and I believe that a nice way to raise the mathematical skills of people(especially students!) is to familiarize them with games and encourage them to use their minds and think on their own ideas. 
I have studied too many puzzle games and I have found too many excellent puzzle games.
But I believe that board games and card games are more effective and I want to find a board game or a card game which have almost all of the following properties:

- The game can be played by 8-9 players (preferably 8 players!)
- The time of the workshops is Limited to 60-90 minutes. Let's assume the time is 90 minutes! (I must learn them the rules in at most 10-15 minutes, and I want a game such that we can do it 2 or 3 times in one workshop.)
- Also, after the first round that the game was played, I want to give them a low-level analysis.
- Also, I Prefer the games, which had a possibility to make some low-level riddles and challenges to involve their minds. (For example, Yahtzee gives me the opportunity to give them some simple probabilistic problems. Also by a problem, I do not mean a mathematical problem, every exciting challenge is welcome.)

I know so many exciting board games but most of them cannot be played by 8 players, and the others are not fit in the limited time of the workshop, because they have too many rules, I prefer a game with simple rules!
For example, [Kriegspiel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kriegspiel_(chess)) is a very nice board game, but it is played by only two players and it is very hard to handle it in workshops! If the number of players was 2, then I could reduce chess to a very very simple board game, and then they can play it like Kriegspiel!

Also, I have a trouble to find a suitable tag!

Comment: @Joe W , My dear Joe W, Where did you recommend me to ask for game recommendations? Could you guide me where should I ask?

Comment: You should ask https://www.reddit.com/r/boardgames or https://boardgamegeek.com/forum/8/boardgamegeek/recommendations.